# error when try to get data from json angular

Tags: angularjs, json

i try to get the data json from factory. i got nothing from the json and i try to look on my console and i got this

```
angular.min.js:123 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://api.myjson.com/bins/d5nyl","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

please enlighten me for this kind of error

experience.html

```
  <tr ng-repeat="experience in experiences" class="">
      <td><p>{{experience.no}}</p></td>
      <td><p>{{experience.name}}</p></td>
    </tr>
```

(Controller)

```
angular.module('app').controller('experienceCtrl',['$scope','Experiences',function($scope,Experiences){
$scope.experiences= Experiences.get();
}]);
```

(SERVICES) experience.js

```
angular.module('app').factory('Experiences',['$http', function($http){
      return{
        get: function(){
          return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/d5nyl').then(function(response){
            return response.data;
          });
        }
      };
    }])
```

Comment: Unless your angular application is downloaded from `https://api.myjson.com`, or CORS is enabled by `https://api.myjson.com/bins/d5nyl`, you MAY NOT send AJAX requests to this URL. It's forbidden by the browser. That's why you get an error, with status -1.

Comment: instead of  `$scope.experiences= Experiences.get();` try

  `Experiences.get().then(function(response){
    console.log('Success:', response);
    $scope.experiences = response.data;
    }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Error', err);
    });`

Comment: @pro.mean i try with your code on console its says success. but still didnt show anything on my table. do i need some edit on my other code?

Comment: You are getting `"status":-1` means your server is unavailable. But in your case json link is returning data and checked your code myself in jsfiddle, it's working properly. It might be CORS issue.

Comment: Can you log `$scope.experiences` when you get success(from pro.means update)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `$scope.experiences` is the promise object and `return response.data;` is returning to nothing. You need to use the promise object in your controller to assign the data.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('experienceCtrl',
    ['$scope','Experiences',function($scope,Experiences){

    Experiences.get()
    .then(function(response) { $scope.experiences = response.data; });
}]);

angular.module('app').factory('Experiences',['$http', function($http){
    return {
        get: function(){
          return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/d5nyl');
        }
    }
}]);
```